# Create cumulative column in power bi

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns, cumulative-sum

I should create a cumulative total column on power bi.
i have a dataset like this:

| Date | KPI | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/02/2022 | 1 | 200 |
| 01/02/2022 | 1 | 250 |
| 01/03/2022 | 1 | 150 |
| 01/01/2022 | 2 | 350 |
| 01/01/2022 | 2 | 450 |

I created a measure that correctly calculates the cumulative total for me. But I should enter this cumulative total for Kpi on column.

Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: Could you re-write your question to be more clear what you are after. Share the DAX for your measure, and what do you mean by "But I should enter this cumulative total for Kpi on column"